# How is it possible to have an interface implemented as a protected method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, interface

I just stumbled across `IController` and noticed that it has a method `Execute`. My question is that given that `Controller` derives from `ControllerBase` which implements the interface `IController`, how is it that `ControllerBase` can implement `Execute` as `protected virtual`?

My understanding is that an interface must be implemented as a public method. My understanding of this is further complicated as you can't call `Execute` on an instantiated `Controller` and you must instead cast it to an instance of `IController`.

How is it possible to have an interface implemented as a protected method?

To add a bit more, I know about explicit interface implementation, however if you [view the source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs) for `ControllerBase` at you will see that the method is implemented as `protected virtual void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)`

Comment: Could you post your compiling code here?

Comment: @Konstantin Spirin: He's talking about `System.Web.Mvc.IController` and `System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called explicit Interface Implementation.

> A class that implements an interface can explicitly implement a member
>   of that interface. **When a member is explicitly implemented, it
>   cannot be accessed through a class instance, but only through an
>   instance of the interface**.

Read more on MSDN: [Explicit Interface Implementation Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Simple sample:

```
interface IControl
{
    void Paint();
}

public class SampleClass : IControl
{
    void IControl.Paint()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("IControl.Paint");
    }

    protected void Paint()
    {
        // you can declare that one, because IControl.Paint is already fulfilled.
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
var instance = new SampleClass();

// can't do that:
// instance.Paint();

// but can do that:
((IControl)instance).Paint();
```

Comment: I understand this, however I didn't think this was the case given that the source implements the method as follows: `protected virtual void Execute(RequestContext requestContext)`. The method isn't explicitly implemented. See http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs

Comment: See the last method in the code: there is `void IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)` as the end - an explicit implementation of your interface member.

Comment: Well spotted sir. I completely missed that one!

Comment: @Sam Because the interface contract is already fulfilled by explicit implementation, you can declare another method with the same name. And it can have any access modifier. Hope everything is clear now.